# video not playing ios 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, asihttprequest

I am trying to play videos from url which my web service returns using MPMoviePlayerViewController. A sample url returned is:

```
http://view.vzaar.com/1128188/player
```

Which i pass to MPMoviePlayerViewController. Do you think this url is compatible to be played?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the source of that page, and it's an html page. I did find a html5 source url. Try:
http://view.vzaar.com/1128188/video

**Yes, with above url.** I just tried it in xcode and I got it to work.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://view.vzaar.com/1128188/video"];

   self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

   [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
   [self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
   [self.view addSubview: self.moviePlayer.view];

   [self.moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: perfect @Michael Ozeryansky...:)

Comment: When i click done in the player view, nothing happens. i want to return to my previous view?

Comment: issue is still there..video is played some times instantly but sometimes it is stuck at loading

Comment: My done button returns the video, so I don't know about that. And the iOS simulator doesn't work the exact same as a device, so try it on the device.

Answer (score 0):

**No**. It can't be played because it's an HTML page with a flash player embedded. Change your web service to return the video directly, possibly in a different URL.